# Run client-only Outlooks rules more often

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My Outlook rules regulate moving the emails to folders and notifying me about some of them. Thus I have to rely on rules, which are client-only.

However, I often see the delay between receiving the message into the Inbox folder and it being moved to the folder, which is specified in a client-only rule.

How can I increase the frequency of rules running?
Ideally, I would like to run client-only rules as soon as new message arrives.
`Outlook Version 2005 (Build 12827.20336 Click-to-Run)`

UPD: An example of one of my rules:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with example.com in the recipient's address
move it to Example folder
  and Display a Desktop Alert
  and stop processing more rules
```

Comment: I assume you have the rules set to `after email received` - so they are run after you receive an email. the `when` section has the triggers.

Comment: @Zina I am not sure, what exactly do you mean, or where is this setting. However, each of my rules starts with "Apply this rule after the message arrives"

Comment: Sorry, my Outlook is on my work computer, but yes, exactly that setting. It means the rule will be applied after Outlook receives it. So every time your Outlook receives a message it will be run through those rules....

Comment: @Zina However, that's not what happens, and it bothers me. I mean, it doesn't happen instantaneously.

Comment: how complex are your rules and what is the time-span it takes to happen?

Comment: @Zina the rules are not much more complex, than the example rule, but there are ~50 of them. Right now I am able to spot the messages 24 hours old still in the Inbox.

Comment: are all the rules enabled? I had an issue with too many rules/parameters that some got disabled. You should maybe change the order of the rules, I would try to put first the one which doesn't seem to be picked up "immediately".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem via enabling Visual Basic, and running the rules using the `Application_NewMail` event. This made the rules really run after every mail reception operation.

For the instruction, how to enable Visual Basic for your Outlook, please, see [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/a/292534/438376) or [this illustrated instruction](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/run-vba-code-outlook/).

In Visual Basic Editor in Outlook add a Module and paste this code:

```
Sub RunRules(ColRules As Object)

    Dim myRule As Outlook.rule      

    For Each myRule In ColRules
        ' Rules we want to run
        myRule.Execute ShowProgress:=False
        Debug.Print myRule.name
        
        ' Actually, this is strange, because it processess every item, so should stop on the first rule, which has such condition
        Dim oAction As Outlook.RuleAction
        For Each oAction In myRule.Actions
            If oAction.Enabled = True Then
                If oAction.ActionType = olRuleActionStop Then
                    Exit For
                End If

                'add more actions here
            End If
        Next
        
    Next
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Public Sub RunAllRules()

  Dim ColRules As Outlook.Rules
  Dim ErrDesc As String
  Dim ErrNum As Long
  Dim InxStoreCrnt As Long
  Dim RuleCrnt As Outlook.rule

  With Session
    For InxStoreCrnt = 1 To .Stores.Count
      With .Stores(InxStoreCrnt)
        Debug.Print .DisplayName
        Set ColRules = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ColRules = .GetRules()
        ErrNum = Err.Number
        ErrDesc = Err.Description
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ErrNum <> 0 Then
          Debug.Print "  " & ErrNum & " " & ErrDesc
        Else
          If Not ColRules Is Nothing Then
            If ColRules.Count = 0 Then
              Debug.Print "  no rules in this store"
            Else
              Call RunRules(ColRules)
            End If
          Else
            Debug.Print " No error but GetRules returned Nothing"
          End If
        End If
      End With
      Set ColRules = Nothing
    Next
  End With

End Sub
```

Then paste the following into your `Microsoft Outlook Objects` → `ThisOutlookSession`:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
    RunAllRules
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As Zina mentioned above, the outlook rule will be applied every time your Outlook receives a message when you set Apply this rule after the message arrives. Please check the status of all your rules and see if they have been all enabled properly.